# Access registry from Silverlight OOB

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

Can I access `Registry` from `Silverlight Out Of Browser`, I just want to search/read the key and get key value pairs. Is this possible?

Or, is there any other way like running a `powershell script`, or launching some other exe to know the values, how can I get the return values from these script/exe to my silverlight application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can do it using [RegRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
    using (dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"))
    {
          var key = shell.RegRead(@"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\......");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OOB can use COM objects, so pretty much "anything" is possible (but it will be Windows specific of course).

That does mean having to develop a COM module yourself (unless you can find one off-the-shelf).

*There may be an easier way to access registry, so you may want to leave this question open a while.*