# Access to Registry object in Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, registry

I have a Silverlight Application.
I need to get registry values, and I used Microsoft.Win32 .
Still, when I'm trying to access Registry object

```
string path = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"....);
```

the `Registry` is marked by red underline, and the error is:

> **"Cannot access internal class 'Registry' here."**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As referenced here:

[Access registry from Silverlight OOB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7185983/5233410)

and

[Reading from the registry with Silverlight](https://csharpdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/reading-from-the-registry-with-silverlight/)

it is possible once certain criteria are met. The gist of accessing the registry from silverlight application is :

```cs
using (dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")){
    var key = shell.RegRead(@"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\......");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering me.